# Splitting a sequence of characters but preserving the string

Tags: java, android, regex

A programmer at my office made a bit of a retarded database, so I'm stuck with a problem.
I've got a String I need to split into 4 parts, so I can read the data from the indexes.

The string I've got is this:

> aimer|4-28-2-2.mp3=12###

The array I'd like to get back is:

> 1. aimer
> 2. 4-28-2-2.mp3
> 3. 12
> 4. ###

The Java code I'm currently using:

```
String assignmentRaw = "aimer|4-28-2-2.mp3=12###";
String[] assignmentSplit = assignmentRaw.split("\\||=");

for(String assignment : assignmentSplit)
    Log.i(ElkeDagApplication.DEBUG_TAG, assignment);
```

And returns:

> 1. aimer
> 2. 4-28-2-2.mp3
> 3. 12###

Comment: will there always be two digits in the number### sequence?

Comment: @mcalex No, the number can be of any length.

Comment: So... the first part of #3 can be of any length. Can the second part also be of any length, or is it by any chance fixed? Is there any other constraint like e.g. the first part will always consist of only numbers? Anything?

Comment: @TofferJ The first part will always be a number and the second part will always be a sequence of #. So something like this: 43##, 2####, 345###.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requirement for the last split is: a digit on the left and # on the right you can do this

```
String[] assignmentSplit = assignmentRaw.split("\\||=|(?<=\\d)(?=#)");
```

`(?<=\\d)` is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks for a digit on the left

`(?=#)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks for a "#" on the right